What is causing my box-shadow to not have the size of element?
I tested this in chrome and firefox:


:root {
  --menu-clr-back:#84774d;
  --menu-clr-text:#eeeeee;
  --menu-clr-hover-back:#eeeeee;
  --menu-clr-hover-text:#84774d;
  --menu-padding: 0.2em;
  --menu-separator: 2px;
  --menu-box-shadow:0.1em 0.1em 0.1em #0008;
}

/* all menu items */
nav>h1 {display:none;}
nav ul {
  color: var(--menu-clr-text);
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;padding:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:flex;
}
nav li {
  position:relative;
  padding: var(--menu-padding);
  background: var(--menu-clr-back);
}

/* top level menu */
nav ul:not(nav ul ul) {
}

/* top level menu-items */
nav ul:not(nav ul ul)>li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: var(--menu-separator);
}
/* top level menu-items */
nav ul:not(nav ul ul)>li:last-child {
  margin-right: none;
}

/* all sub menus */
nav ul ul {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  box-shadow:var(--menu-box-shadow);
}

/* first sub menu */
nav ul ul:not(ul ul ul) {
  top:100%;
  left:0;
}

/* all sub menus */
nav li:hover>ul {
  display:inline-block;
}

nav li:hover {
  color: var(--menu-clr-hover-text);
  background: var(--menu-clr-hover-back);
}

nav li li:has(ul)::after {
  content:'▸';
  display:inline-flex;
}

nav li li
{
  width:100%;
}
<nav>
<ul>
<li>[Item 1]</li>
<li>[Item 2]

<ul>

<li>[Item 2.1]</li>
<li>[Item 2.2] some</li>
<li>[Item 2.3]</li>

</ul>


</li>
<li>[Item 3]</li>
<li>[Item 4]

<ul>

<li>[Item 4.1] some</li>
<li>[Item 4.2]

<ul>

<li>[Item 4.2.1]
<ul>
<li>[Item 4.2.1.1]</li>
<li>[Item 4.2.1.2]</li>
<li>[Item 4.2.1.3]</li>

</ul>


<li>[Item 4.2.2]</li>
<li>[Item 4.2.3]</li>

</ul>


</li>

<li>[Item 4.3]</li>

</ul>
</li>

<li>[Item 5]</li>
<li>[Item 6]

<ul>

<li>[Item 6.1]</li>
<li>[Item 6.2]</li>
<li>[Item 6.3]</li>

</ul>
</li>


</ul>
</nav>



The box-shadow of the menu panels is not the size of the elements. But why is this, and how can I fix it?
Also: what is moving submenu 4.2.1 a little bit up?

what is moving submenu 4.2.1 a little bit up? >>> Check pseudo class ::after > '▸'

Your drop-shadow doesn't appear as large as your drop-down menu as your defining the width of the list items (li) as 100% and then then you're adding on the padding. If you style list items as box-sizing: border-box the 100% width will match the drop-down menu so the shadows will align.
As for your pseudo element not aligning with the adjacent item, it is because, as @NINE points out, it's a problem with the caret. If you apply line-height: 1; to the pseudo element, it will make it the same height as the text.


:root {
  --menu-clr-back:#84774d;
  --menu-clr-text:#eeeeee;
  --menu-clr-hover-back:#eeeeee;
  --menu-clr-hover-text:#84774d;
  --menu-padding: 0.2em;
  --menu-separator: 2px;
  --menu-box-shadow:0.1em 0.1em 0.1em #0008;
}

/* all menu items */
nav>h1 {display:none;}
nav ul {
  color: var(--menu-clr-text);
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;padding:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:flex;
}
nav li {
  position:relative;
  padding: var(--menu-padding);
  background: var(--menu-clr-back);
}

/* top level menu */
nav ul:not(nav ul ul) {
}

/* top level menu-items */
nav ul:not(nav ul ul)>li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: var(--menu-separator);
}
/* top level menu-items */
nav ul:not(nav ul ul)>li:last-child {
  margin-right: none;
}

/* all sub menus */
nav ul ul {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  box-shadow:var(--menu-box-shadow);
}

/* first sub menu */
nav ul ul:not(ul ul ul) {
  top:100%;
  left:0;
}

/* all sub menus */
nav li:hover>ul {
  display:inline-block;
}

nav li:hover {
  color: var(--menu-clr-hover-text);
  background: var(--menu-clr-hover-back);
}

nav li li:has(ul)::after {
  content:'▸';
  display:inline-flex;
  line-height: 1;
}

nav li li
{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<nav>
<ul>
<li>[Item 1]</li>
<li>[Item 2]

<ul>

<li>[Item 2.1]</li>
<li>[Item 2.2] some</li>
<li>[Item 2.3]</li>

</ul>


</li>
<li>[Item 3]</li>
<li>[Item 4]

<ul>

<li>[Item 4.1] some</li>
<li>[Item 4.2]

<ul>

<li>[Item 4.2.1]
<ul>
<li>[Item 4.2.1.1]</li>
<li>[Item 4.2.1.2]</li>
<li>[Item 4.2.1.3]</li>

</ul>


<li>[Item 4.2.2]</li>
<li>[Item 4.2.3]</li>

</ul>


</li>

<li>[Item 4.3]</li>

</ul>
</li>

<li>[Item 5]</li>
<li>[Item 6]

<ul>

<li>[Item 6.1]</li>
<li>[Item 6.2]</li>
<li>[Item 6.3]</li>

</ul>
</li>


</ul>
</nav>



Your --menu-box-shadow:0.1em 0.1em 0.1em #0008; definition has small sizes (0.1em is 1.6px).

as far as I know, rgba can be written with 4 digits in case you dont need 8.

@rhavin - I stand corrected. I've always used the rgba() functional notion, but four digits is easier. Thanks for the info.
